# Arduino hangs after some time

Tags: arduino-mega, atmega328

I am using Atmega328p with 5V power supply,
My Arduino getting hangs [or auto restarts] after some times.

I am using libraries:

- Wire.h
- CRC32.h
- EEPROM.h
- Arduino.h
- TimerOne.h
- RtcDS3231.h
- SoftwareSerial.h
- Adafruit_NeoPixel.h
- avr/wdt.h

I have tried to search, some people are deny to use software serial library.

[image]

Comment: it's possibly some error in *your* code

Comment: This is my code, can you guide me...
https://github.com/savaliyadnk/arduinoswitch

Comment: don't use String. use C strings (zero terminated char array) https://majenko.co.uk/blog/evils-arduino-strings

Comment: That is only a minimal circuit in theory. Can you show us a photo? We like to see where the decoupling capacitors are and how close the crystal with the 22pF capacitors to the atmega328p is.

Comment: Do you have 100nF connected to aref and vcc? It should be to gnd. All gnd and all vcc should be connected to the power. All of them. You have no decoupling capacitors. They are **not** an optional extra according to this page: http://www.gammon.com.au/bootloader

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this will fix your problem, but this is a major error:

```
  char buf1[8], buf2[6];
  sprintf(buf1, "%08lu", myvote.mydate);
  sprintf(buf2, "%06lu", myvote.mytime);
```

Take a look at [sprintf function reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/)

> A terminating null character is automatically appended after the content.

So, the text buffers are too small. It should be at least:

```
char buf1[9], buf2[7];
```